# What exactly is wrong with this mosfet switch circuit?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

[image: Blue line: square wave output. Green line: Output at R2 (Load resistor)]

Ok I thought I had mosfets figured out, at above 10V they were on (for my piece) and at 0V they were off, why isn't V2 (green) putting out the same waveform as the switching source (V1, blue)? I even included a pull down resistor to account for the internal capacitance and a resistor to protect the gate. What exactly am I missing to make V2 oscillate between 0-12 depending on the input of the driving oscillator?

(Also ignore the diode I don't know why I put it there but it has 0 effect on the circuit)

Sorry for such a probably basic question but your responses will be very helpful. Thank you :)

n004 measured between R3 and M1
n001 measured between R2 and M1

Comment: V2 should provide a constant 12 volts - my question would be "why do we see any signal on V2?"  Please label the nodes you are measuring - we don't know where n001 or n004 are.

Comment: updated the question sorry

Comment: just the wires in between, connecting them to the mosfet

Comment: Circuit is OK. Search for mistakes, you did.

Comment: Choose a specific MOSFET. The generic one is not very good. V1 and V2 are not the blue and green traces. You say the diode is  a mistake, then remove it and try again.

Comment: Yeah choosing a specific MOSFET was the issue, I didn't know that the generic one was bad. Thank you!!!!